# Problem with integral and maclaurin Series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am working on some problems and I can't seem to figure this one out.

The question asks, find/derive the maclaurin series for the following function

F(x)= $\int_0^x$$e^{t^2}$dt

Here is what I did, 
I know the maclaurin for e^x so I substituted in t^2 instead of x. this gave me a series of the form $$(1+t^2+t^4/2+t^6/3!+t^8/4!+ ….)$$

then I integrated the first couple of components to get $$( t + t^3/3 +t^5/{10}+t^7/42+t^9/216+t^{11}/1320+…+C)$$

But now I am not sure what to do next. I can't seem to find a general formula for the bottom of the integrated components, and I am not even sure if that is what I am supposed to do.

Could anyone please help?

Thank you

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{4}erf(-x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt=\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty {t^{2n} \over n!}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {t^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)n!}+C\Big|_0^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)n!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty {0^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)n!}$$

Comment: Thanks, but how do I take account the x and such